# GeoTools and PostGIS with ESPG:3857

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I'm trying to use both PostGIS and GeoTools with the same ESPG:3857 projection, however, it looks like the projections in PostGIS and GeoTools differ.

This is what I have in PostGIS:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

Here's GeoTools:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

I've tried using the PostGIS one with GeoTools, but it cannot parse it due to the EXTENSION element. Of course, I could update PostGIS with the GeoTools one, but can anyone tell why they are different?

I'm using GeoTools 10.0, Postgres 9.3 with PostGIS 2.1. I'm just trying to convert a EPSG:4326 point into EPSG:3857, and vice versa. The code works:

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
    Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
    Point targetPoint = (Point) JTS.transform(point, transform);
```

but the targetPoint that I get is different from ST_Transform(point, 3857) that I get from PostGIS.

So for example, for

```
(41.937832, -87.642970)
```

I get from GeoTools with code above:

```
POINT (4668498.103213854 -24771604.62292875)
```

and from PostGIS

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-87.642970, 41.937832), 4326), 3857))

POINT(-9756370.79201015 5151671.52336743)
```

Any solution on how to make these two work together? I'd really like to convert between projections in both SQL and Java.

Thanks!

Comment: The two projections are not different. What is different is their representation on different software.

Comment: If you post what values you're getting, someone can tell you which one is correct at least.

Comment: @mkennedy - added an example

Comment: see http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html might help?

Comment: that is unless you are really interested in a point in antarctica?

Comment: PostGIS point is spot-on compared to ArcGIS. As iant pointed out, it looks like the input for GeoTools needs to be flipped (use longitude,latitude order).

Comment: It's actually (lat,lon) for GeoTools, and (lon, lat) for PostGIS :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always [be aware of the axis order](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html). PostGIS *always* uses the axis order: longitude (x), latitude (y).

```
-- Somewhere in Chicago, USA
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-87.642970, 41.937832), 4326), 3857));
-- POINT(-9756370.79201015 5151671.52336743)

-- Somewhere in Antarctica
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(41.937832, -87.642970), 4326), 3857));
-- POINT(4668498.10321386 -24771604.6229288)
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was passing a flipped version into GeoTools (lon, lat), whereas it should've been (lat,lon)...