# Good projection for covering most of the world

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, geotools

I'm writing an application for building navigation routes thru the city streets, and not quite sure what projection would be best.

I tried EPSG:3587, however, the tools I'm using - GeoTools and PostGIS - seem to disagree on how to interpret this one ( [GeoTools and PostGIS with ESPG:3857](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74214/geotools-and-postgis-with-espg3857) )

Could someone recommend a similar projection that would cover most of the world, and be appropriate for looking at the data at the street level only? The data I'm working with is OSM for maps and a lot of WGS84 lat,lon coordinates for way points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the "proper" ellipsoidal Mercator ([EPSG:3395](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/)). That projection is truly conformal, as opposed to the "Web Mercator" (EPSG:3857), which uses a spherical approximation. This comes at a computational cost, however (about a factor of 5 for the forward and reverse projection, according to the table on slide 10 of [Noel Zinn's presentation](http://www.hydrometronics.com/downloads/Web%20Mercator%20-%20Non-Conformal,%20Non-Mercator%20%28notes%29.pdf)).

Also, it's probably a good idea to fix the problems you have with EPSG:3857 instead of changing projections. EPSG:3857 is the quasi-standard for small-scale web maps, so if your setup has hiccups with that, chances are you'll run into trouble with other projections as well.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I figured out the my issues with EPSG:3857, so I will move on with it - but now I know what to fallback to :)